# Even after successfully installing pyramid-arima, can't import it

Tags: pip, installation, pyramid-arima

Can't import `pyramid.arima` even after installing it in jupyter notebook as well as checking the same in anaconda prompt.

Tried installing it in jupyter notebook and then checked the same in the command promp of anaconda.

```
!pip install pyramid-arima

from pyramid.arima import auto_arima
```

> Actual Result: No module named 'pyramid.arima'

Answer (score 0):

Closing and opening the jupyter notebook did the trick.

N.B - Sorry for bothering you guys. :P